# serial port problem

Tags: raspbian, python

find a solution about run python program getting error simple program

```
import serial 
ser =serial.serial ("dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate = 9600) 
ser.write("code") 
ser.close()

error attributeerror 'module' object has no attribute 'serial'
```

Answer (score 2):

Capitalisation is important. You want `serial.Serial()` instead of `serial.serial()`

You've also not put the correct path to the serial device - `dev/ttyAMA0` would be relative to the place the user runs the script from (so would only work if you run it from `/`).

Your code should be:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600) 
ser.write("code") 
ser.close()
```

See http://www.elinux.org/Serial_port_programming for more examples.